# Подсчет товаров в категориях рекурсия

Tags: php

Прошу помощи, сваял функцию, которая должна считать, а она считает только до первого предка, прошу помощи.

Сама функция:

```
function col_tovar($id,$c=0){
//считаем число товаров в категории
$t = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tovar` WHERE `id_cat`=".$id.""),0);

static $n=0;
$n = $t + $c;
//смотрим какие категории есть в этой
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `kat` WHERE `mid`=".$id);

while($idcat = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
col_tovar($idcat[0],$n);
}
if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `kat` WHERE `mid`=".$id),0) == 0){
    return $n;
    unset($n);
   }else return $n;
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Результат - это то, что надо посчитать или что это? Ваша функция игнорирует возвращаемое ей самой значение - какая уж тут рекурсия? Используйте `$x=col_tovar($idcat[0],$n);` и делайте что-то с этим `$x`

Comment: Да в $n суммируется число товаров, только почему то выше 2 уровня не идет. Спасибо за совет попробую Ваш вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так должно работать правильно.

Некоторые стилевые правки:

- поправил отступы;
- sql обычно принято называть текст запроса, а не его результат, лучше использовать, например, rows или result;
- не стоит, по возможности, усложнять операцию в строке, поэтому я разделил mysql_query и mysql_result;
- mysql_fetch_array выдает результат в форме, которая здесь не используется. Заменил на более простую mysql_fetch_row

```php
function col_tovar($id) {
  //считаем число товаров в категории
  $rows = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tovar` WHERE `id_cat`=".$id);
  $n = mysql_result($rows, 0);

  //смотрим какие подкатегории есть в этой категории
  $rows = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `kat` WHERE `mid`=".$id);

  while ($idcat = mysql_fetch_row($rows)) {
    $n += col_tovar($idcat[0]);
  }

  return $n;
}
```

Comment: А поподробне? Картинка у нас есть. Можете ещё содержимое базы добавить в вопрос. Это будут исходные данные. А затем несколько примеров с тем, какое число Вы ожидаете и какое получено.

Comment: Очень важно видеть структуру и пример содержимого базы. Что-то я подозреваю там не совсем так, как Вы считаете...

Comment: Вот как я бы построил Вашу базу - [пример базы](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ec3f3/1). Посмотрите, пожалуйста, и скажите так ли у Вас. Если иначе, то как?

Comment: Сергей, структура базы следующая.Таблица kat: id | mid | vis name таблица tovar: id | id_cat | name | ...

Comment: Все так как вы указали выше по ссылке, но почему не работает я пока не могу понять:)